# Ruby on Rails named routes with absolute path from application root

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

I'm trying to set up named routes for page:

- www.myhost.com/blog/about

  `(map.about '/about', :controller => 'page', :action => 'about')`

And I have another route for a resource:

- www.myhost.com/blog/post/3

  `(map.resources :posts)`

Now I don't know how should I link to "about" page. If I use

- a) `<%= link_to 'About', about_url %>`
  or
- b) `<%= link_to 'About', 'about'   %>`

It works fine only when I go to `blog/posts` and `blog/about`. When I open `blog/post/1`, then the link to about page gets an url `blog/post/about`.

How can I force it to make an absolute path from the application root?

Comment: Option (b) is wrong, but are you sure you get that same behavior when you use (a)? If so, please paste the html source generated by link_to about_url.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HTML output for (a) and (b) should be like this. The issue will occur only on using method (b).

a)

```
<a href="http://127.0.0.1:3000/about">About</a>
```

b)

```
<a href="about">About</a>
```

if you need the absolute path from application root, you can pass `about_path` as the second argument to the `link_to` helper.(`<%= link_to 'About', about_path %>`). That will produce your links as shown below.

```
<a href="/about">About</a>
```

Comment: I thought I tried with about_url, but now testing it for the second time - it works!